# Inserting wrong data in table wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

When I insert the serialize data in the postmeta table the data is modified while inserting like:

```
s:107:"a:4:{s:6:"page_1";s:5:"third";s:6:"page_2";s:5:"first";s:6:"page_3";s:6:"fourth";s:6:"page_4";s:5:"fifth";}";
```

but when I print this data before inserting it is displaying this that is right:

```
a:4:{s:6:"page_1";s:5:"third";s:6:"page_2";s:5:"first";s:6:"page_3";s:6:"fourth";s:6:"page_4";s:5:"fifth";}
```

while inserting it is automatically add   s:107:" in front of data or "; in back of data.

Can any one please tell me why it is inserting like this.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

The `s` means `string`.
`107` stands for the size of the string.

Comment: But i don't want it cause it cause the front end issue can you suggest me how i resolve this.